# Manufacturer not working in search

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, product-list, search, manufacturer

In the product list, I show the manufacturer and everything works fine. But when I make a search, instead of showing the manufacturer’s name it shows No. I use the following code to show the brands :

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```

I'm using magento 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Diagnosing your actual problem:**

- Ensure that the product collection used for search includes the manufacturer attribute or that the manufacturer attribute is set in the backend to display on the frontend (see screenshot below).
- Ensure that the `manufacturer` attr is set for the **appropriate store view**! In the manage catalog product edit view, ensure that the dropdown is being set for the value of the store view, **not the store/website/default view**.
- Make sure you're reindexed. If you're on CE, run the indexer manually. If on EE make sure your indexes are refreshed from cron or via `$ php shell/indexer.php reindexall`.
- Clear all of your caches. Flush cache storage. `rm -rf var/cache` and all the destructive things. Check for the existance of a `/tmp/magento` folder.
- Disable/enable flat catalog and reindex.

**Enabling an attribute for frontend/product page/collection visibility:**

[image]

**Why this happens:**

So, there is a *valid reason* why Magento returns "No" when there is no data available. The method `getFrontend` returns an object that is a subclass of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Abstract`.

In the method `getValue`, if there are no options available / set, it defaults to output boolean. Thus, the value of "No" - which is the frontend boolean equivalent of `false`:

```
public function getValue(Varien_Object $object)
{
    $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
    if (in_array($this->getConfigField('input'), array('select','boolean'))) {
        $valueOption = $this->getOption($value);
        if (!$valueOption) {
            $opt     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean');
//....
```

Once the above troubleshooting points are done - if you still receive "No" and it's an appropriate response (e.g. you have no manufacturer set on a product, and on purpose) you may want to conditionally test the output before echoing:

```
$value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $value=="No" ? "" : $value;
```