# how to select one manufacturer id of loaded products?

Tags: attributes

I want to select ids of a specific brand when I have the name and the Id of a product for example 111

I found out the ID of manufacturer by using `getManufacturer()`

I used this code in template/catalog/product/list.phtml :

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_collection_selected=$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 111));
    foreach ($_collection_selected as $_product_selected):
                $product_selected_ids[]=$_product_selected->getId();
                 print_r($product_selected_ids);
            endforeach;
```

but it shows me all the products I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: What is Block instance i.e. your $this, but most likely your collection is already been loaded.

Comment: What I meant it's already been loaded from magento and you can't filter it like that (not tested). And yes you need to use Code

Comment: yeah I got it mostly by http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/manufacturer-not-working-in-search/9797#9797 it seems I am close to solution

Comment: I think this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280392/magento-load-only-configurable-products

Comment: what should i use for type_id?

Comment: You need to use Manufacturer Id and not Product Id on your addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 111))

Comment: yes that is what i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem probably lies in the fact that the collection you try to adjust is already loaded. When a collection is loaded, the query is already executed and the data is ready for usage in the collection.

The only way to adjust the collection after loading is by calling a `$collection->clear()`. If you want mor detailed technical information you can check the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` in which the `clear()` method can be found.

Comment: I didn't write $this->getLoadedProductCollection() it was there before and it doesn't have problem and I don't change it so no need to call it

Comment: Yes, correct. The call was already there and you did not made a change it. But afterwards, the 2nd line in your snippet, you try to append a attribute filter to that very collection. This new attribute filter will be ignored by Magento, since the collection you try to adjust is already in a 'loaded' state. Hence the result is still all the products. You can only apply attribute filters before the collection is loaded. Hence the loaded state must be cleared as I tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: you don't know how much I should thank you! brilliant!

Comment: Sounds like you made some progress :). Good luck with the rest!

Comment: yeah I learned a big tip from you,you solved my problem that i am struggling from the morning